# Having trouble with texturing

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm relatively new to blender and 3D modelling. I've just started creating a game with ue4 and decided that I would like to create my own static meshes for world objects and floor tiles. Anyway! I modelled my different floor tiles got them all as I'd hope for but when it came to texturing, I seem to have hit a brick wall. I started with a cube and extruded the walls. I used the subdivide tool to round the edges and the loop and cut to square the floor and walls. I did an a smart uv unwrap and applied a simple grass texture to the whole mesh. I keep getting these solid colours bordering each square and I cant find a way to remove them. I also tried a manual unwrap and still no joy. If anyway can suggest a solution I would be most grateful.

Cheers

Pete  [image]

Comment: If you keep changing your mesh your UV map wont withstand long. Unwrap at the end

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried applying the SubSurf Modifier? If not, make a copy of the object and apply the Subsurf to the copy, then remap it. If that doesn't work, can you show us the UV map with texture?